# how to install postgis2.5 on ubuntu16 for postgresql11

Tags: postgis

how to install postgis2.5 on ubuntu16 for postgresql11?

I had installed postgresql11 from source code.
Now, I want to install postgis2.5 .
I try to install by apt .

```
apt-cache search postgis  
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

also

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install postgis postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3
```

#### There is no directory in  ./mypg11/share/contrib

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the answer you are after you should see if you can hang on for postgis to catch up with postgres 12. They released a few days ago for postgres 12 rc1. I'd expect in the next week or so they are likely to put a release out for the pg12 official release. You'll benefit from speed improvements, particularly regarding data updates / shorter lock times, and faster queries.